# It is possible to rasterize sns.distplot(,rug=true)?

Tags: pdf, matplotlib, seaborn

In Matplotlib it is possible to plot a very long array `A` using `rasterize=True`, as in the following:

```
plt.plot(A, rasterise=True)
```

This typically lowers the memory usage.

It is possible to do the same when  drawing a *rugplot* on the support axis in Seaborn's `sns.distplot`(see http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html)? In fact, such a rugplot can consist of many points and consume lot of memory, too.

EDIT:
As noticed in the answer below, this does not lower memory RAM consumption, but we saving the plot on file in pdf format, can  alter (i.e., *decrease* or even *increase*, under certain circumstances) the dimension of the file on disk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seaborn [distplot](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html), like many other seaborn plots, allows to pass keyword arguments to the underlying matplotlib functions.

In this case, `distplot` has a keyword argument `rug_kws`, which accepts a dictionary of keyword arguments to be passed to the [`rugplot`](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.rugplot.html#seaborn.rugplot). Those are again transfered to the underlying matplotlib `axvline` function.

As such, you can easily provide `rasterized=True` to `axvline` via

```
ax = sns.distplot(x, rug=True, hist=False, rug_kws=dict(rasterized=True))
```

However, I'm not sure if this has the desired effect of lowering memory consumption. In general, rasterization is applied when saving the figure, so the plot shown on the screen will not be affected at all.
During the process of saving, the rasterization has to be applied, which takes more time and memory than without rasterization.

While bitmap files like png are completely rasterized anyways and will not be affected at all, the generated vector files (like pdf, eps or svg) may even have a larger filesize compared to their unrasterized counterparts. 
Rasterization will then only pay off when actually opening such a file (e.g. pdf in a viewer) or processing it (e.g. in latex) where having the rasterized part consumes much less memory and allowing for faster rendering on the screen or printing.

Comment: Awesome, that is what is was looking for. Thanks also for the remark on the "memory consumption"... I should have said "space on disk". I guess that saving with `plt.save_fig('file.pdf', dpi=100)` should be enough to save the figure in a smaller pdf file. Is that right?

Comment: Not necessarily, it really depends on the number of points to draw. For a low number of points <= 1000 unrasterized pdf will probably be smaller. But the good thing is with the solution from the answer you can simply try both cases and compare filesize, printing speed or whatever you like.

Comment: Indeed my data contain definetively *much* more that 1000 points! (while printing speed is not a problem)